# Multiple Submit Buttons problem in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, webwork

Trying to work with multiple submit buttons within a single form in struts2 application but not able to work.
here is the jsp code i am using

```
<tr>
<td class="button"><input type="submit" value="Import"
        name="destinationImport" class="button"></td>
    <td class="button"><input type="submit" value="Export"
        name="destinationExport" class="button"></td>
</tr>
```

here is the java part

```
private boolean destinationImport;
private boolean destinationExport;
//and the respective setters and getters
```

but i am sure is that Struts2 type convertor is having problem converting the String value to boolean 
do any one have idea how to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods : getDestinationExport / setDestinationExport should deal with String, since your values: "Export" and "Import" aren't convertible directly to boolean type.
If you need convert it by internal rule, place corresponding code inside setDestinationExport. Something like that:

```
 public void setDestinationExport(String arg){
     destinationExport = "Export".equals(arg);
     destinationImport = "Import".equals(arg);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but this will tightly coupled my form with the action and any change in the button value will cause a lot more changes and more over for i18n this will fail

Comment: @umesh awasthi - note you can use origin Struts2 submit button, that exactly specifies method to call: <s:submit key="gl.Save" method="doSave"/>  Where key - is i18n key and method in your action

Answer (score 0):

This way should works

```
private boolean destinationImport = false;
private boolean destinationExport = false;

public void setDestinationImport(boolean destinationImport) {
  this.destinationImport = true;
}

public void setDestinationExport(boolean destinationExport) {
  this.destinationExport = true;
}
```

Reference:
http://serpensalbus.com/blog/tricking-struts2-multiple-submit-buttons/